# Performance while sending mail with nodemailer

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a performance related problem. I have a reservation system where after reservation is put into database the `onWrite` cloud function send email with `nodemailer` and deletes event so it's no longer available for other people to reserve.

The problems:
- I don't know how to make a callback that would confirm sending email
- sending email and removing event takes even up to a minute which is really slow

I don't want to show in client code how to remove events from database from obvious reasons. What are other options here?

```
exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/reservations/{reservation}').onWrite(event => {

    const moment = require('moment');
    moment.locale('pl');

    admin.database().ref('/users').orderByChild('place').equalTo(event.data.val().placeId).once('child_added', function(snapshot) {     

        // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: '(...)',      
            port: 465,
            secure: true, // secure:true for port 465, secure:false for port 587
            auth: {
                user: '(...)', // TODO move to config()
                pass: '(...)' // TODO move to config()
            }
        });

        // setup email data with unicode symbols
        const mailOptions = {       
            from: 'whatever', // sender address - TODO make it dynamically populated
            //replyTo: 'put user's email here',
            to: snapshot.val().email,
            bcc: '(...)',
            subject: 'Nowa rezerwacja', // Subject line - TODO make it dynamically populated
            text: 'Nowa rezerwacja\n'
                + "\nImię i nazwisko: " + event.data.val().name
                + "\nTelefon: " + event.data.val().number
                + "\nEmail: " + event.data.val().email
                + "\nTermin: " + moment.utc(event.data.val().start).format("D MMMM YYYY [o godzinie] HH:mm")
                + "\nDo: " + event.data.val().scheduleName, // plain text body
            html: 'Nowa rezerwacja<br>'
                + "<br>Imię i nazwisko: " + event.data.val().name
                + "<br>Telefon: " + event.data.val().number
                + "<br>Email: " + event.data.val().email
                + "<br>Termin: " + moment.utc(event.data.val().start).format("D MMMM YYYY [o godzinie] HH:mm")
                + "<br>Do: " + event.data.val().scheduleName
        };

        // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => { // TODO should be returned
            if (error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }

            console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);

            //move it elsewhere - maybe HTTP trigger?
            admin.database().ref('events/' + event.data.val().eventKey).remove();   

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: It sounds like you have two questions.  One is how to receive confirmation that an email was send, the other is how to make that faster.  BTW, without showing some code that's actually having problems, it's hard to make suggestions.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated my question. How to receive confirmation is one thing because this is not that important - more important is to have event instantly removed from database because in that period someone else could make same reservation and that event would be overbooked so to speak.

Comment: Why not use onCreate?  It will trigger only once when the reservation is added.  You won't have to worry about multiple functions running on the same record.  Also, you're going to need to return a promise from this function to make Cloud Functions wait for all this work to finish.

Comment: You're right, I don't know why I didn't used `onCreate` - thanks for pointing it out! But still can I get a callback from cloud function or there is no way around and I have to show in end-user code how I remove data?

Comment: Just to make it more clear: priority is to have a callback after the event was removed. Mail can be sent asynchronously and with delay.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "callback" in this case.

Comment: The flow I intend is like this: someone clicks on 'Book that table' -> database removes that table from `events` node then writes a reservation in `reservations` node and then after reservation is successfully saved sends callback to the browser. Browser then updates the view with all other tables available. And in the meantime, asynchronously, email confirmation is send, but it's already working.